# PyQGIS cannot render 32 bit tiff

Tags: raster, pyqgis, rendering

I have this code:

```
def main():

    qgisApp = QgsApplication([], True)
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', True)
    QgsApplication.initQgis()

    layers = []

    fileName = "."
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
path = fileInfo.filePath()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(path, baseName)

    layers.append(rlayer)

    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers(layers)

    img = QImage(QSize(800, 600), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)

    p = QPainter()
    p.begin(img)
    p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

    layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
    lst = layers.keys()
    renderer = QgsMapRenderer()
    renderer.setLayerSet(lst)

    extent = renderer.fullExtent()
    rect = QgsRectangle(extent)
    # print rect.toString()
    rect.scale(1.1)
    renderer.setExtent(rect)

    # set output size
    renderer.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())

    # do the rendering
    renderer.render(p)
    p.end()

    img.save('test.png', 'png')

    QgsApplication.exitQgis()
main()
```

This only works for pictures that are not 32 bit TIFFs. Is this due to me having an old version of QGIS? How can I get past this?

Comment: Could it be a GDAL version issue, rather than QGIS version?